# does not contain a definiton for mobileservice

Tags: windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

I folowed the steps windows azure page on how to connect my app to the mobile service and I keep getting this error in the final line of the code: "PhoneApp1.App does not contain a definition for 'mobileservice' ".
I added a refernce to WindowsAzure.MobileServices package and it didnt help. what can I do?

this is my code:

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{

    public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Signup_Page : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://ppmobserv.azure-mobile.net/",
            "kiejvLOaNFeLZKYsFqhPQMzRgXEylc66"
        );

        public Signup_Page()
        {  
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void InsertItem()
        {
            Item item = new Item { Text = "Awesome item" };
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>().InsertAsync(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: which tutorial exactly you followed, any link?

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/2mhfogl.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is meant to be put in App.xaml.cs :

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "https://ppmobserv.azure-mobile.net/",
        "kiejvLOaNFeLZKYsFqhPQMzRgXEylc66"
    );
```

so that you can access it from `Signup_Page` this way :

```
await App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>().InsertAsync(item);
```

if you put definition of `MobileService` (the first code block above) in `Signup_Page` instead of App.xaml.cs, you need access it without `App.` prefix :

```
await MobileService.GetTable<Item>().InsertAsync(item);
```